# C - Type Name : Number?

Tags: c, memory-management

I was wondering what the following code is doing exactly? I know it's something to do with memory alignment but when I ask for the sizeof(vehicle) it prints 20 but the struct's actual size is 22. I just need to understand how this works, thanks!

```
  struct vehicle {
    short wheels:8;
    short fuelTank : 6;
    short weight;
    char license[16];
  };

  printf("\n%d", sizeof(struct vehicle));

  20
```

Comment: Also format `%d` for a `size_t` argument is wrong. It probably only works because your are on a 32bit machine. Use `%zu` instead: `size_t` is an unsigned type (therefore the `u`) and `z` ensures that it uses the correct width.

Comment: Use `"%zu\n"`, not `"\n%d"`. `\n` marks the *end* of a line.

Answer (score 2):

Memory will be allocated as (assuming memory word size is of `8` bits)

```
 struct vehicle {
    short wheels:8;       // 1 byte
    short fuelTank : 6;
    // padd 2 bits to make fuelTank of 1 byte.
    short weight;         // 2 bytes.
    char license[16];     // 16 bytes.
 };
```

`1 + 1 + 2 + 16 = 20` bytes.

Comment: but how are 2 bits being padded?

Comment: @user3373360; as per the [padding rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding).

Comment: okay and if I were to change the :8 to a :6 after wheels, what exactly is that changing and what difference would it make?

Comment: I just don't understand what the value of "8" is doing as opposed to "6"? What does 8 stand for?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a machine with a word size of 32bit.  The two first fields fit in a whole 16bit word as they occupy `8 + 6 = 14` bits.  The second field, while not a bitfield (doesn't have the `:<number>` thing to allocate space in bits) can fit another 16 bits word to complete a 32 bit word, so the three first fields can pack in a 32bit word (4 bytes) if the architecture allows to access the memory in 16 bit quantities.  Finaly, if you add 16 characters to that, this gives the 20 bytes that `sizeof` operator sends to printf.

Why do you assume the `sizeof (struct vehicle)` is 22 bytes?  You allowed the compiler to print it and it said it's 20.  Compilers are free to pad (or not) the structures to achieve better performance.  That's an architecture dependency, and as you have not said architecture and compiler used, it is not possible to go further.

For example, 32bit intel arch allows to pad words at even boundaries without performance penalties, so this is a good selection in order to save memory.  On other architectures, perhaps it's not allowed to use 16bit integers and data must be padded to fit the third field (leading to 22 bytes for the whole structure)

The only warranty you have when sizing data is that the compiler must allocate enough space to fit everything in an efficient way, so the only thing you can assume from that declaration is that it will occupy at least the minimum space to represent one field of 8 bit, other of 6, a complete short (I'll assume a short is 16 bit) and 16 characters (assuming 8 bits per char) it ammounts to `8 + 6 + 16 + 16*8 = 158 bits` minimum.

Suppose we are writing a compiler for **D. Knuth MIX machine**.  As it's stated in his book *Fundamental Algorithms*, this machine has an unspecified byte size of 64..100 bytes, requiring five to construct one addressable word (plus a binary sign).  If you had a byte size independent compiler (one that compiles for any MIX machine, without assumptions of byte size)  you have to use no more than 64 possible values per byte, leading to 6 bit per byte.  You then would assume the second field fills one complete byte (and the sign drawn from the word it belongs to) and the first field needs two complete bytes (using half of the values for negative values)  The third field might be in the second word, filling three complete bytes (`6*3 = 18`) and the sign of that word.  The next 16 chars can begin on the next word, summing up to five complete words, so the whole structure will have `1 + 1 + 4 = 6` words, or 30 bytes.  But if you want to handle effectively three signed fields, you'll need three complete words for the three fields (as each has a sign field only) leading to 7 words or 35 bytes.

I have suggested this example because of the particular characteristics of this architecture, that makes one to think on not so uncommon architectures that some time ago where in common use (the first machines ever built where not binary based, like some of these MIX machines)

### Note

You can try to print the actual offsets of the fields, to see where in the structure are located and see where the compiler is padding.

```
#define OFFSET(Typ, field) ((int)&((Typ *)0)->field)
```

(Note, edited)

This macro will tell you the offset as an `int`.  Use it as `OFFSET(struct vehicle, weight)` or `OFFSET(struct vehicle, license[3])`

### Note

I had to edit the last macro definition as it complains on some architectures as the conversion of pointer -> int is not always possible (on 64bit architectures, it looses some bits) so it's better to compute the difference of two pointers, which is a proper `size_t` value, than to convert it directly from pointer.

```
#define OFFSET(Typ, field) ((char *)&((Typ *)0)->field - (char *)0)
```